# How to change a single symbol of otf font in pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, unicode, greek

I'm using a `.otf` font with pdflatex. The default symbol for the greek letter beta is

[image]

which I'm not a fan of. Looking through the otf file, I found another beta symbol that I'd like to use as the default one:

[image]

I don't know the command that produces the desired beta, otherwise I'd just switch them around with `\renewcommand`. The unicode code for the beta I want is `U+03D0`. How can I swap them?

Comment: you can not be using the otf font directly in pdftex, pdftex fonts have at most 256 characters, you need to go back to the encoding that you specified when making the tfm font and make a font that uses U+03D0 instead of U+03B2

Comment: I've used texmital for the encoding of lowercase greek letters, but going through it I don't see any reference to any unicode code, just 16 groups of 8 symbols, and the `\beta` command is in the second group (labelled `0x8`). There are however 128 spots left vacant, currently filled with `.notdef`'s. Could I use one of them to include the symbol I want? If yes, how?

Comment: so make a copy of that enc file and replace /beta by the name of the symbol in the font, which you should be able to check in a font editor but /uni03D0 might work

Comment: Yes, it worked. Feel free to make an answer out of these comments so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not be using the otf font directly in pdftex, pdftex fonts have at most 256 characters. You need to go back to the encoding that you specified when making the tfm font and make a font that uses U+03D0 instead of U+03B2

so make a copy of that enc file and replace `/beta` by the name of the symbol in the font, which you should be able to check in a font editor but `/uni03D0` might work